# Running nose.run() multiples time with different config  for  Webdriver Python script 

Tags: python, webdriver, nosetests

I'm wondering how get nose.run() twice using different configuration in a python script

1. I have a nosetest (unit test) where it needs to be run on 2 types
   of browsers using webdriver .
2. The print command below will show the browser is assigned to
   browser 1 and 2 respectively.
3. However nose.run always run using browser2 variable twice instead
   of running browser1 and then browser 2.

```
parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read('config.ini')
browser = parser.get('Selenium_Config','browser1')
print browser
nose.run()
browser = parser.get('Selenium_Config','browser2')
print browser
nose.run()
```

Comment: You can use Selenium Grid to run selenium tests with multiple browsers.  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2